Are the EIOPA risk-free rates different for S2 vs IORPII?
EIOPA publish various risk-free rates to be used by insurance and pension funds to value liabilities.
My question is, are these rates the same for both Solvency II and IORPII regulations? If not, what is the difference?

Where did you read that EIOPA publishes RFRs for pensions funds? As far as I know the IORP II directive is more about governance (three lines of defence etc).
